# VirtualBox extension pack is installed--How do I add it to VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04

I'm a long-time user of VirtualBox. I allowed Ubuntu 22.04 to upgrade it to .38, and the .34 extension pack caused my VM to fail. Using Tools.Preferences.Extensions, I removed the old extension pack, and the VM now loads.

I used Synaptic to install the .38 extension pack. I click the plus sign, but I can't find the file it wants. I see virtualbox-ext in usr/share, but it is empty.

What is the extension file name? Where is it?

Comment: The Extension Pack version must match the Virtualbox's version. And it's just a file you can download from their site and then double-clicking it will open Virtualbox and offer to install it.

Comment: OK, then why does Aptitude install it? I'll try downloading and clicking on it...

Comment: And, it worked. Thanks! Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it...